# Accessing variable bindings in Elixir/Erlang using the int module

Tags: erlang, elixir

I have been experimenting with using the [int module](http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/int.html#snapshot-0) for debugging Elixir/Erlang, but I can't figure out how to examine bound variables. I attach an IEx process (meta process) to another IEx process running a mix project and use the functions in the `int` module to set breakpoints, step, and resume code, and that all works.
I know there is the `get_binding` function, but the documentation says this is meant to be called from a conditional breakpoint condition function. In any case I don't know how to get the bindings to pass to this function.

Looking at the source code in `int.erl` I see there are other functions that can be called from a *meta process*, including the various `meta` functions. My attempt at calling `meta(Meta, bindings, Stack)` after reaching a breakpoint in the process being debugged locks up the meta process. My call looked like this (Elixir):

```
:int.meta(meta, :bindings, :nostack)
```

I tried looking at the source code for the Erlang graphical debugger, but I can't quite follow it. Can someone explain to me how to get the bindings after reaching a break point and after stepping code?